# Les trois sens (ou plus) de « comme quoi »

Tags: sens, pronoms, conjonctions, interrogative

Dans le Larousse [*comme quoi*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/comme/17457/expression?q=comme+quoi#16001663) est défini ainsi :

> *1*. *Comme quoi*, ce qui montre bien que, ce qui est bien la preuve que.

Je reste ahuri par cela. La première fois que je l'ai rencontré, j'ai imaginé qu'il signifiait :

> *2*. Similaire à quoi, semblable à ce qui vient d'être mentionné.

En outre, d'après [ce fil de discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2038809) et [ceci](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=127234), quand *comme quoi* figure seul, il peut vouloir dire :

> *3*. Tout est possible ; et alors ? ; la belle affaire !

Encore que point *2* tienne dans l'exemple donné plus bas, 
je m'interroge sur la genèse, l'intuition, et sur ce qui motive les points *1*, *2*, et *3*. Le *1* ne révèle rien à propos des *2* et *3*. Comment pourrait-on les deviner, démêler, et prédire ? Comment les concilier tous ? *1* et *3* découlent-ils de ma prévision *2* ?

> Il se passe des choses étranges chez toi.
>   — Des choses étranges ? **Comme quoi** ?

Note personnelle : Dans cet exemple, dont voici la [provenance](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=747243), le point 2 s'applique.

Comment: Le sens 3 me paraît étrange, et ton lien n'est visiblement pas le bon, d'où vient il ?

Comment: @Gilles: Merci beaucoup. Je l'ai amendé.

Comment: Ah, d'accord. Effectivement, on peut construire un exemple où l'on dit « comme quoi » en sous-entendant « tout est possible ». Mais ce serait exagéré de considérer que « comme quoi » signifie « tout est possible ». On retrouve une expression similaire en anglais : « *which goes to show* ». On peut dire « *which goes to show…* » en sous-entendant « *anything is possible* ». C'est pareil en français.

Comment: @Gilles: Je vous suis reconnaissant et vous prie de le réécrire en tant que réponse, pour laquelle je plussoyerai. Toutefois, pensez-vous que **comme quoi** = *"which goes to show"* ? Je pensais plutôt à *"like what"* ?

Comment: Il me semble que Gilles a raison a propos de ton point 3. Attention à ne pas se laisser piéger par cet idiome figé (*« Comme quoi... (sous-entendu : ...tout est possible!) »*), évoquant avec une sorte d'effet de suspension la possibilité toujours présente d'être surpris par la vie, parfois pour souligner la vanité inhérente à toute certitude. A mettre en lien, à mon sens, avec les "brèves de comptoir" chère à Gourio. Mais cela ne constitue pas un autre sens ou un autre usage de la forme grammaticale *comme quoi*.

Answer (score 3):

Le petit Robert suggère que l'on peut remplacer **comme quoi** par :

> - *disant que* :  faites-lui un certificat **comme quoi** son état de santé nécessite une repos.
> - *d'où il s'ensuit que, ce qui prouve que* : Il n'est pas venu, **comme quoi** nous avons bien fait de ne pas compter sur lui.

Le Littré suggère d'abord  : **comme quoi**, de quelle façon.

> - Voilà **comme quoi** il est fort dangereux d'avoir demi-étudié, BALZAC, *liv. III, lett. 9*
> - Vous savez **comme quoi** je vous suis tout acquise, CORNEILLE, *Rodogune I, 7*
> - Comme quoi est aussi interrogatif mais très peu usité en cet emploi : **Comme quoi** *n'êtes-vous pas persuadé ?*

et précise ensuite :

> **comme quoi** est de difficile explication :
>
>  *Comme* a parfois le sens de comment ; et l'on dit,
> interrogativement, ayant mal entendu : **comme quoi ?**
>
> - Cette étoffe est
>   comme du satin ; si on a mal entendu, on dira dans le langage très
>   familier : **comme quoi ?**
>
> **Comme quoi** est devenu de la sorte une locution faite, qui s'est
> introduite pour ne signifier rien de plus que *comment*.

Mais le 'comme quoi ?' cité peut être une interrogation sur la signification de la question, contraction de :

> - quelles sont les choses étranges dont tu me parles et que je ne connais pas, que je n'imagine pas ? As-tu des exemples ?