# « Comme quoi » signifiant « comment »

Tags: usage, france, locutions-adverbiales

**La Petite Fadette**, George Sand

> Landry alla souper chez lui avec son frère ; et,
> comme celui-ci était bien soucieux de tout ce qui
> s’était passé, il lui raconta **comme quoi** il avait eu
> maille à partir la veille au soir avec le feu follet,
> et comment la petite Fadette l’en ayant délivré,
> soit par courage, soit par magie, elle lui avait
> demandé pour sa récompense de la faire danser
> sept fois à la fête de la Saint-Andoche.

On trouve le sens de la tournure adverbiale « comme quoi » au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoi).

> C. − Fam. [Dans la tournure comme quoi]
>
> 1. [Introduisant une interr. indir.] Synon. de comment.Germain raconta comme quoi il avait été forcé de ramener la petite Marie (Sand,La Mare au diable, XV ds Grev.1969, § 995).

C'est une tournure qui me parait inusitée de nos jours ; cependant, le dictionnaire qui ne stipule aucune mention sur l'usage, mis à part que c'est un terme familier, laisse entendre qu'elle appartient au vocabulaire courant. Est-ce exact ?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7670/1893

Comment: @livresque It is related and adds much information on a general study of the combination "comme quoi"; yet, it does not include this particular meaning I mention. The sense "comment" is included but there is not precision about usage except "sometimes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De nos jours, l'emploi est « souvent considéré comme peu recommandable » ; employé surtout avec *raconter/expliquer*, il était **usuel** ou non marqué au 17<sup>e</sup>, à l'époque de Vaugelas, et **littéraire** à celle de Sand, au 19<sup>e</sup>, et se rapproche de « **que** » alors qu'il découle du sens de « comment/de quelle façon » qu'avait *comme quoi* originairement ; il est perçu comme « **très familier** » aujourd'hui. (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 419 b, note H2, 1123 f in fine)

Comment: Ce n'est donc pas « comment » dans le texte que je mentionne, mais « que ». « 1123 » n'a rien à voir avec « comment », mais ce qui y est dit est bon à savoir.

Comment: Oui, _que_. 419 et 1123 traitent de _comme quoi_. _Comment_ est une des valeurs de _comme quoi_ originairement mais le sens se rapproche davantage de _que_ par la suite. Tu peux aussi jeter un coup d'oeil à 719 d).